# Alter "Apply coupon"

Tags: commerce

I am developing an advanced coupon module, two-thirds of it has been completed so far; But to apply coupons for products/variation, considering that commerce does not use the Drupal hooks
**how can change the behavior of applying a coupon?**

https://www.drupal.org/project/advance_coupon

Download from here
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/advance_coupon/-/tree/1.0.0-dev?ref_type=heads

Now I know, the coupon apply is from the following file
/modules/contrib/commerce/modules/promotion/src/Plugin/Commerce/InlineForm/CouponRedemption.php
its code:

```
/**
    Submit callback for the "Apply coupon" button.
   /
  public static function applyCoupon(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
    $parents = array_slice($triggering_element['#parents'], 0, -1);
    $inline_form = NestedArray::getValue($form, $parents);
    // Clear the coupon code input.
    $user_input = &$form_state->getUserInput();
    NestedArray::setValue($user_input, array_merge($parents, ['code']), '');

    if (isset($inline_form['code']['#coupon_id'])) {
      $order_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order');
      /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
      $order = $order_storage->load($inline_form['#configuration']['order_id']);
      $order->get('coupons')->appendItem($inline_form['code']['#coupon_id']);
      $order->save();
    }
    $form_state->setRebuild();
  }
```